Values aren't matching a list (python)
I am trying to have a user type in a hostname and if it matches then return other items in the list
I was able to append it to new list if item is online but I can't seem to return a match if they match and I have verified that the host is in this list (its pointed via another api route)
# Check if workstations list has data
    
def firewall_on_demand():
    # Check if workstations list has data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        devices_online = []
        # Get the JSON data from the POST request
        data = request.get_json()
        hostname_to_lookup = data.get('pcName')
        host_status = None  # Default status if no match is found
        task = None  # Default task if no match is found

        workstations = devices.workstations
        for i in workstations:
            if i['host_status'] == "Online":
                # Append both 'device_id' and 'hostname' to devices_online
                devices_online.append({
                    "hostname": i['hostname'],
                    "device_id": i['device_id']
                })
            for device in devices_online:
                if device["hostname"] == hostname_to_lookup:
                    device_id = device["device_id"]
                    current_app.logger.info(
                        device_id
                    )
                    host_status = "online"
                    break  # Exit loop once a match is found

                #task = hbfw_on_demand(device_id)  # Simulate task creation

            return jsonify({"task": task, "host_status": host_status})


The for device in devices_online: loop probably shouldn't be inside the for i in workstations: loop, it should be after it.

Or just use if i['hostname'] == hostname_to_lookup, there's no need for the devices_online list.

The return statement shouldn't be inside the loop. It will return on the first iteration, even if the workstation wasn't found.

It looks like the whole problem is that you have an extra level of indentation starting with for device in devices_online:. Dedent everything starting there and it should do what you want.

I don't think it's causing the specific problem you're asking about, but you may also run into trouble where at one point for host_status you use "Online" and in another it's "online" with all lower-case.  Best to pick one or the other, or normalize the strings before comparison in all cases.
